# Can someone tell my why exec() in PHP isn't working for Windows?

Tags: php, command-line, cmd, exec

Here is the command I have:

```
$cmdline = 'cd \\ & convert C:\\websites\\disneypinplace.com\\beta\\pin\\PD'.$pinid.'-front.jpg -resize 750x750 C:\\websites\\disneypinplace.com\\beta\\pin\\PD'.$pinid.'-front.jpg ';
exec($cmdline);
```

Note the that `convert` command line executable (which is an image processor) must be executed  outside of C:\Windows\system32 for some reason, which is why I do a `cd \` at the beginning.

I run my PHP code but nothing happens. When I paste the same code into my command line, it works just fine.

I am running PHP 5.4 on Windows Server 2012

Comment: is convert in the path of your webserver's shell? does it have the rights to actually execute it?

Comment: Yuo cannot pass multiple commands to exec

Answer (score 0):

Adding the full path to `convert` solved it for me:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16\\convert.exe"
```